# Can the Poisson summation formula break?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

The [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) states if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
then $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) $ where $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}dx \; e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\;f(x) $$

The fine print is that $f$ needs to be [Schwartz class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) or be a [tempered distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) such as the [Dirac-delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta_n(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{2\pi i n x} $$

It then says the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) is its own Fourier transform.

Are there counterexamples where the left and right sides converge yet these traces do not agree?

---

**Edit**  As discussed in the comments, it appears in [Katznelson's textbook](http://tailieuhoctap.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/katznelson-y-an-introduction-to-harmonic-analysis-cup-2004299s_mcf_.pdf) although I don't understand his example very well - convolving a function with the Fejer kernel many times at different scales.

---

**Edit** Can anyone fill in details of Lucia's response?

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes?

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher beats me

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher I conjecture the downvotes might've been caused by john's attitude towards the answer he's received. I'm not saying I consider this a valid downvote reason myself though.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher Apparently having an unpopular opinion on the usage of downvotes will lead to lot's of downvotes from users on this site.

Comment: (Some people are just angry...)

Comment: What is wrong with you people? The questions has 42 downvotes and 39 upvotes! Actually 40 upvoted counting mine.

Comment: Side note: the theory of Fourier Tranform for measures implies that the PSF also holds for continuous functions $f$ with compact support for which $\widehat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 93):

Exercise 15 of Chapter VI (Section 1) of Katznelson's book "An introduction to Harmonic analysis" gives an example of a continuous $L^1$ function $f$ where both sides of the Poisson summation formula are absolutely convergent, but the formula does not hold.

To add a little to this, the usual proof of Poisson summation begins 
by periodizing $f$ setting $F(x) = \sum_{n\in {\Bbb Z}} f(x+n)$ and then 
computing the Fourier series of $F(x)$.  The idea in Katznelson's example is 
that even if $f$ is somewhat nice (e.g. continuous and $L^1$) it need not be the 
case that $F$ is nice (e.g. it could be discontinuous).  In particular Katznelson's 
example constructs a nice $f$ for which $F$ turns out to be $1$ on all of ${\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z}$ except for being discontinuous at $0$ where it takes the value $0$.  So there 
is a problem with the Fourier series for $F$ at $0$, and hence with the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  My answer gave a reference to the literature showing there are counterexamples to the Poisson summation formula, even if $f$ and ${\hat f}$ are somewhat nice.

Comment: I conjecture that a lot of the time a downvote is a botched upvote (via a mouse slip), so don't lose too much sleep over this.

Comment: I am not crazy about Katnelson's example.  Can you explain why it works or think of another one?

Comment: @Lucia **I** downvoted.  This is not a good answer because it points to something I Googled in 5 minutes.  Here is [Katznelson's book](http://tailieuhoctap.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/katznelson-y-an-introduction-to-harmonic-analysis-cup-2004299s_mcf_.pdf) online for free.

Comment: @JohnMangual: Lucia provided an answer for your question. Your not liking it (sorry, "not being crazy about it") is not a reason to downvote. The fact that you googled it in five minutes means that you should have not asked your question, or asked for an answer different from Katznelson (explaining why). Doing what you did is a good way to get people to never look at your questions.

Comment: I agree with @IgorRivin. (If John was unhappy with the example given by Lucia, and had already seen the example in Katznelson's book, then why not leave a comment while downvoting?

Comment: @JohnMangual OK, here is a relevant comment: **please explain** what it is you want displayed or explained in the counterexamples which is not present in the example pointed to by Lucia. If you give people an idea of what you are looking for, they have better chance of giving answers that you are not "not crazy about"