# Conditions for Poisson summation (for discontinuous functions)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Let $G$ be an locally compact abelian group with $\Gamma$ a discrete cocompact subgroup. I'm looking for precise conditions by which Poisson summation formula holds. That is, for some function $f$ on $G$, possibly discountinuous, we have
$$
\sum_{g \in \Gamma} f(g) =  \sum_{g \in \Gamma} \hat{f}(g) 
$$
where $\hat{f}$ denotes the abelian Fourier transform of $f$ with respect to a fixed additive character of $G$ and self-dual with respect to the measure $dx$ on $G$. Most of the time one requires (1) $f$ to be in $L^1(G)$, and (2) for the dual sum to converge (absolutely, I think, because an interchange of integral and sum is involved).

Examples such as [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140233/can-poisson-summation-formula-break?rq=1) suggest that we need (3) the sum
$$
F(x) = \sum_{g\in\Gamma}f(xg) 
$$
to be continuous, at least at the identity $g = $ Id.

Most texts tend to assume $f$ is Schwartz or at least continuous. I haven't been able to find a good reference for these conditions for Poisson summation *without* this condition. (The closest I found was in Bourbaki XXXII.)

Also, if a second question is permitted, the continuity of $F(x)$ does not seem obvious how to prove, in particulr when $f$ itself is not continuous.

Comment: I have trouble parsing your first formula, if $f$ is a function in $G$, $\hat f \in \hat G$, how do you know that $\Gamma \leq \hat G$?

Comment: In the versions I know of Poisson summation formula in LCA groups, for example in Folland's Abstract Harmonic Anaysis Thm 4.42 what you do is to prove that the averaging operator $f \mapsto F$ and the restriction operator $f \mapsto f{|}_{\Gamma^\perp}$ are intertwined by the Fourier transform. In order to make sense of your result you will need the restriction $f{|}_{H^\perp} to be defined.

Comment: There are subgroup-restriction results that work for non-continuous functions, for example De Leeuw's original formulation of the restriction theorem required that every value $f(x)$ shall be the limit of the averages on balls centered on $x$, but I do not known if you can prove Poisson's formula with that type of condition.

Comment: You mean that $f$ is a function *on* $G$, and $\hat{f}$ on $\hat{G}$. I've conveniently chosen the character so that $\Gamma^\perp$ can be identified with $\Gamma$.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in my first comment.